# I have an English question on this post -> Firebase: Should I add GoogleService-Info.plist to .gitignore?

Tags: idioms, programming

I was reading this StackOverflow answer but I have an English problem and cannot understand the answer. this is the link [Firebase: Should I add GoogleService-Info.plist to .gitignore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937175/firebase-should-i-add-googleservice-info-plist-to-gitignore)?

In the answer, the guy uses "you're better off leaving it out for one big reason", but I cannot understand the meaning of "leaving it out" and I'm still not sure if that means I should add GoogleService-Info.plist to .gitignore or not.

Could anyone tell me I should put the file into .gitignore?

Comment: Is your confusion with what [*leave out*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/leave%20out) means, or what an *ignore list* is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While it's not the end of the world if you commit
> GoogleService-Info.plist (similarly, on Android,
> google-services.json), you're better off leaving it out for one big
> reason: You're making it clear that others who build your code that
> they should be setting up their own Firebase project to host its
> configuration and data (because your project simply won't build with
> that file missing).

"It" is "GoogleService-Info.plist".  "Leave it out" means to not include that file in the group of files that are uploaded into the public repository.